# gl surface errors, unable to run app

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I cant find a anwser anywhere about the errors i am having.  I found one's similar on stackeroverflow but they dont have the same error codes and their soultions were not working.
I created a webview with a ad.  The ad loads up all good, but the webview wont load up, and i keep getting errors about it.  Things i found on other peoples quetsions where "load it on a phone that will work, something is wrong with the emulator" or "go to your avd and switch your settings about the gpu". But none of this works.  I saw on a another website that this will happen to hacked devices. But i dont really understand that. . . .   Here are my errors:

```
 E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
 E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
 E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
 E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
 E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff()    failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Best guess based on your commentary:

- You're using GLES2
- You're running in the AOSP emulator
- You don't have hardware acceleration enabled

If all of those are true, then enabling hardware acceleration in the AVD (or, from the command line, with `-gpu on`) should correct the problem.

I suspect the issue is that the AOSP emulator itself only implements GLES1.  If you switch to hardware accelerated mode, the GPU commands are mostly forwarded to the host GPU, and GLES2 is supported.